# What does it mean for partial derivative to exist but not continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

> What does it mean for partial derivative to exist but not continuous?

Continuous partial derivatives imply differentiability and differentiability imply continuity of a function and the existence of partial derivatives. I also understand that any other implication of this statement is false.

Comment: And your question is… ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The title, I think.

Comment: A function can exist but not be continuous. Take such a function $f(x)$ on an interval and let $F(x)$ be an antiderivative of $f(x)$. Then $F'(x)$ exists and is not continuous.

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $f(0) = 0$ is differentiable, but its derivative is not continuous.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_classes)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822023/graphical-explanation-of-the-difference-between-c1-and-c2-function

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have a function of several variables that has *partial* derivatives everywhere, but which is not fully *differentiable* everywhere. In such a case the partial derivatives will be discontinuous.

A typical example of the kind of functions we're talking about would be

$$ \begin{align}
f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) &= r\sin(2\theta) & \quad \text{for }r>0 \\
f(0,0) &= 0 \end{align} $$

This has both partial derivatives everywhere, but they are not continuous. We have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ at $(0,0)$ but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2$ at $(x,0)$ for every $x>0$. And the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, because the linear mapping induced by the partial derivatives doesn't approximate it well enough in directions *other than* the one the partial derivatives were taken in.

---

Even in one dimension, it is possible to be differentiable everywhere, but not *continuously* differentiable; the classical example is
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when }x=0 \\
x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$