# What does it mean to have a continuous (and discontinuous) partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I think that I understand the increment theorem, however I do not really see how we get the corollary:

"If the partial derivatives $ƒx$ and $ƒy$ of a function $ƒ(x, y)$ are continuous throughout an open region R, then ƒ is differentiable at every point of R."

What does it mean that a partial derivative is continuous? Why is it not meant to say that if the function itself is fully continuous, then f is differentiable at every point R, which for me would be easier to see from the interval theorem as we would be able to note that any small change in x and y in f will yield something that has a sufficiently small error that tends to $0$ in terms of its partial derivatives(which we assume exist and so anything in the region R is fully differentiable). What would the concept of a continuous (and by implication, discontinuous) partial derivative be, and why is my intuition of the interval theorem incorrect?

Comment: Have you read this post's answer [what-does-it-mean-for-partial-derivative-to-exist-but-not-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144905/what-does-it-mean-for-partial-derivative-to-exist-but-not-continuous)

Comment: @Joe Yes, but I do not really see the link between the interval theorem and the corollary. Also I am somewhat confused as to how to tell if a partial derivative is continuous or not. For example, if fx and fy are equal to some constant, how do I tell if it is continuous or not, and from this how do we infer that if fy and fx are continuous, they will satisfy the interval theorem.

Comment: I’m not sure what the “increment theorem” or “interval theorem” is, but if your question is how that theorem implies this, I would ask that in a separate post, not one titled as your post is, but I recommend first learning what it means for a partial derivative (or any function) to be discontinuous. Constant funcions àrea definitely continuous (actually for every topology possible on domain & codomain).

Comment: What do you mean by “fully continuous”? It's *not* true that continuity implies differentiability, if that's what you're thinking. As for your question, if you know what the phrase **continuous function** means (as you ought to know before worrying about differentiability), then you already know what it means for the **functions** $f_x$ and $f_y$ to be **continuous**, right?

Comment: @Joe Yes and this is where my confusion comes from. In the example f(x,y)=0 if xy=/=0 and 1 if xy=0, we get partial derivatives fx and fy as constants 0, however the function is not differentiable. However, later on it says that if partial derivatives are continuous, then the function is differentiable. So, my question comes to what makes a partial derivative continuous and how to tell this.

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry I think I just mean continuous over its entire domain. What I meant was that if the partial derivatives fx and fy are continuous through a region R, then the function is differentiable at every point R according to my textbook. Is this an incorrect statement?

Comment: In your example, $\partial_x f$ does not exist at $(0,a)$ for $a\ne 0$, so the partial derivatives do not even exist in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, assuming that's the place at which you're checking differentiability.

Comment: @Ahmed: Yes, that's a correct statement, and that's just what you've written in quotation marks in the question already. But below that, you seem to question it, talking instead about "the function itself" being "fully continuous", and I suppose this refers to the function $f$, not its derivatives?