# How does the increment theorem relate to differentiability of multivariable functions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

The increment theorem (taken from Thomas' Calculus: Early transcendentals):
"Suppose that the first partial derivatives of $ƒ(x, y)$ are defined throughout an open
region $R$ containing the point $(x_0 , y_0)$ and that $ƒ_x$ and $ƒ_y$ are continuous at $(x_0 , y_0)$.
Then the change

a)$∆z= ƒ(x_0 + ∆x, y_0 + ∆y) - ƒ(x_0 , y_0)$
in the value of $ƒ$ that results from moving from $(x_0 , y_0)$ to another point
$(x_0 + ∆x, y_0 + ∆y)$ in $R$ satisfies an equation of the form:

b)$∆z = ƒ_x(x_0 , y_0)∆x + ƒ_y(x_0 , y_0)∆y + \epsilon_1∆x + \epsilon_2∆y$

in which each of $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\rightarrow0$ as both $∆x, ∆y\rightarrow 0$"

There are a number of questions that I have about this:

1. From the above theorem, the corollary "If the partial derivatives $ƒ_x$ and $ƒ_y$ of a function $ƒ(x, y)$ are continuous throughout an open region $R$, then $ƒ$ is differentiable at every point of $R$." is derived.
   However, it seems to me to be unclear as how such a conclusion was reached in particular with regards as to what it means for a partial derivative to be continuous and how this can be told. Since partial derivatives are taken at points where one independent variable is kept constant, then we get examples such as:
   $ƒ(x, y) = 0, xy≠0$ and $ƒ(x, y)=1,xy=0$
   Here, $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ at $f(0,0)$ which would seem to me to suggest that since it is a constant function, we ought to find them continuous. However that would contradict the interval theorem above as it would imply the function is differentiable (which it is not)
2. From the interval theorem, the book then claims that "If a function $ƒ(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0 , y_0)$, then $ƒ$ is continuous at $(x_0 , y_0)$" However, a lot of people have said that differentiability does not imply continuity, so I am a bit confused with regards to what to believe/when to believe that that is the case.
   In addition, I am unsure about the logical steps involved in reaching the conclusion. If we accept the corollary as true, then a differentiable function has both its partial derivatives as continuous and so in b) $∆z$ heads to $0$ as $∆x$ and $∆y$ tend to $0$. However, to me this does not instantly translate to a)that as $∆x$ and $∆y$ tend to $0$, that $∆z$ will have to also tend to $0$, as it appears b) is just a particular case of a).
3. My last question is with regards to whether my general intuition of this theorem is even correct as it has caused me so much confusion. From what I understand, a) sets out a way to check if a function is continuous by allowing us to "access" and "check" points that are $∆x$ and $∆y$ from $x_0$ and $y_0$ which overcomes the limitations of partial derivatives that keep one independent variable constant. From this we find that if there is continuity in the function, we ought to be able to get an approximation in the form of b) of it, within a certain tiny error $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$. If the function is discontinuous (as in my example) then we find that $∆z$ is too large compared to $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ and so the function is not differentiable (expressible in the form of b))

Comment: You’re asking good questions. Since you seem to have a maturity exceeding what’s expected for readers of that text, I’ll recommend you try some of my YouTube lectures, linked in my profile. :)

Comment: The fallacy in your example in item 1 was already pointed out in a comment to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246979/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-continuous-and-discontinuous-partial-derivative) by user Joe. And regarding item 2, I really hope that a lot of people haven't told you **that**, but rather the opposite: continuity does not imply differentiability! (For example, that was what I told you in a comment to that question.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Ah I see that makes sense I think I just mixed the 2 around.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your example, partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$ but they do not exist at any point of the form $(x,0)$ ($x\neq 0$) or $(0,y)$ ($y\neq 0$) since at those points your function jumps along most directions. In other words there is no neighborhood of the origin where your partial derivatives exist. Needless to say, they are not continuous at $(0,0)$.
2. The corollary is true, and continuity follows from $(b)$. Actually, you just need differentiability (which does not require derivatives to be continuous) to get continuity at a point.
3. If your function is only continuous, you cannot expect $(b)$ to take place, since the partial derivatives may not exist, or they may exist but be discontinuous at the point. Differentiability is more than continuity: you not only have $\Delta z\to 0$ as $\Delta x\to 0$ and $\Delta y\to 0$ but the difference $f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)$ is **linear** in $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ in first approximation, a much stronger condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With regards to 1) I am still a bit confused. If x is not equal to 0 but y=0 then f(x,y) is 1 and so $f_x=0$ still for all values of x which would be continuous.

Comment: Yes, but $f_y$ does not exist there. For the same reason, $f_x$ does not exist at points $(0,y)$ if $y\neq 0$. You need both derivatives to be continuous, and in no neighborhood of the origin both of them exist.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you that makes much more sense. I was just wondering if you could explain a bit more about the linear thing. Why is this fact a much stronger condition then the fact Δz→0 as Δx→0 and  Δy→0? Your help is much appreciated :)